# Tags Development Tools

Tags: emacs, pintos

The Makefile in pintos/src produces Emacs-style tags with the command make TAGS or vi-style tags with make tags.

How do I use "tags" to follow along with references to function and variable names. By using M-. function_name?

[https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs140-spring20/pintos/pintos_11.html#SEC159](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eouster/cgi-bin/cs140-spring20/pintos/pintos_11.html#SEC159)

Comment: in a shell run `make TAGS` in the root pintos directory. Then open a C file press `M-.` on an identifier and you should be prompted to load the new TAGS file that was created in the base directory.

Comment: If necessary, use `M-x visit-tags-table`.